# How to fix "Download incomplete" error, when use Content-Length by download via PHP-file

Tags: php, html

I create a downloadt.php file to download my email attachments directly from email Server, without save it on my Webspace. 
I click on a submit button to post the data to my save_attachment.php file.

It works great, but if i add the "Content-Length" Line, it doesn't work every time. So i find out, that not all smartphones-browser work-fine with this line. So i check if there is a Smartphone, and if not, i add the Content-length.
Because i want to know the filesize and download process in Desktop browser.

It works now. But if i try to download bigger files(more than 1-2MB) the download started, but Closed with "incomplete download". small files works great(50 kiloby).

EDIT: in works in chrome. The problem is only in IE...

I tried to Change the Content-type, header("Pragma: public"); header("Expires: 0"); header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');

```
<?php
session_start();

If ((Isset($_POST['uid']) == false) or (Isset($_SESSION['user']) == false) or (Isset($_SESSION['pw']) == false)) {
    echo ("Keine Zuordnung vorhanden");
    return;
}

$get_username = $_SESSION['user'] ;
$get_pw = $_SESSION['pw'] ;
$get_server_in = $_SESSION['server_in'];
$get_uid = $_POST['uid'];
$get_partNum =  $_POST['data-attachment_partNum'];
$get_encoding = $_POST['data-enc'];         

$imap_open= imap_open($get_server_in, $get_username, $get_pw);
$msgno = imap_msgno($imap_open, $get_uid);    

function downloadAttachment($imap, $uid, $partNum, $encoding) {
    $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, imap_msgno($imap, $uid), $partNum);
$filesize = $partStruct->bytes;
$filename = $partStruct->dparameters[0]->value;

    $message = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNum, FT_UID);

$path_info = pathinfo($filename);    

    switch ($encoding) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            $message = imap_8bit($message);
            break;
        case 2:
            $message = imap_binary($message);
            break;
        case 3:
            $message = imap_base64($message);
            break;
        case 4:
            $message = quoted_printable_decode($message);
            break;
    }    

   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');

    if ($_SESSION['mobile'] != "true"){
    header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
       header("Content-Range: 0-".($filesize-1)."/".$filesize);

    }       

    echo $message;             

    //echo $filesize;
         // echo ini_get ( 'memory_limit');
}

downloadAttachment($imap_open, $get_uid, $get_partNum, $get_encoding);

?>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You get the size and then manipulate it with those imap encoding functions. Doesn't that change the number of bytes? Confused about where you get filesize and what is actually output.

Comment: thank you for your help.

I got the filesize from the imap_bodystruct function. 

 $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, imap_msgno($imap, $uid), $partNum);
$filesize = $partStruct->bytes;

header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);

Comment: I would be very surprised to find any browser that doesn't work fine with a `Content-Length` header. More likely you're setting an incorrect value. Why isn't it just `strlen($message)`? And why are you using HTTP 206 and the `Content-Range` header? These are not used for downloading full files.

Comment: I used HTTP 206 cause I looked for a solution and tried some codes....

Comment: I tested to download a pdf file with 1,93MB. I read echo $filesize and the Bytes was correct! For testing some other solution I used strlen(). The filesize wasn‘t correct, only 7bytes